# How do I configure a Word template so it changes the font of a pre-existing document?

Tags: microsoft-word, fonts, styles, templates, microsoft-word-2016

I’m trying to configure a Word 2016 template (Template.dotm) in such a way that it will change the font of all Normal-style text when attached to a pre-existing document.  Currently, the template I’m working with only wants to apply the new font size and line spacing, even though the new Normal font (Arial) has also been specified and saved.

All the tutorials I’ve found say that you need to select “New documents based on this template” in the Normal style window, save that change to the template, then select "Automatically Update Document Styles" when you attach the template to the pre-existing document.  I’ve done both of these things multiple times and neither of them do anything to change what happens when I apply the template to a pre-existing document.

Is what I want even possible, or am I required to manually apply the new styles after attaching the template?

Comment: Is your new template using 'Theme Fonts' (specified on the Design tab)? In other words, for the Normal style, is the font explicitly set to Arial, or is it set to +Body? I encounter this same issue when the template uses Theme Fonts, because the Theme Fonts of the original doc overrule the Theme Fonts of any template I apply, even if I select Automatically update document styles when I apply it. To resolve this, I have to click Fonts on the Design tab, and manually set the Theme Fonts to whatever my new template uses.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this in the past before, but i don't think you need to create template for that. Basically what you need is just Style Set in Design Tab of Word 2016

What i did

1. Edit the style, in your case Normal-style, just exactly you want
2. Go to `Design` `Document Formatting` and click as `Save as New Style Set`
3. Save it, and give it name you can remember, for eg. MyStyle
4. Now open pre-exist document, head back to `Design` `Document Formatting`, and apply set style you just created before. Now the document have the same style with set style you created before